# Application lifecycle test when togging system menus: screen goes black when onvisibilityChange:hidden

Tags: cobalt

I am integrating youtube on cobalt 11. And now I'm testing the application lifecycle test.

1. I send the `suspend` event when I push the menu button (youtube goes to background)
2. I send the `unpause` event when I switch back to youtube. (youtube comes to foreground)
3. I send the `deepLinke` event after the `unpause` event

Sequence of events:

1. `window.onfocus`
2. `window.onblur`
3. `....................?launch=remote`
4. `window.onfocus`
5. `..................:visible`
6. `onvisibilityChange:hidden`
7. `window.onblur`
8. `visible`

When `onvisibilityChange:hidden`, youtube goes to the background; is that right?
This makes the screen turn black.

And why 1. `window.onfocus` and 2. `window.onblur` occur again after youtube has already resumed?

Comment: It is very unclear what you're asking. Have you checked the Stack Overflow guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: The application lifecycle test Expect the logs like above 1 - 8:
I send the event:suspend,unpause,deeplink,pause,unpause, as a senquence.
But I find 2 problem

Comment: The application lifecycle test Expect the logs like above 1 - 8:
I send the event:suspend,unpause,deeplink,pause,unpause, as a senquence.
But I find 2 problem
1.youtube go to background when we push the menu button on remote control,it is not a good experience.
2.Why the logs window.onfocus, window.onblur after launch mode are needed.?Is it a Extra print?

Comment: I got the meaning of this test-case.

Answer (score 0):

If you send the kSbEventTypeSuspend event, then Cobalt will assume that it is hidden and stop rendering to the display.  If Cobalt is meant to remain visible, then do not send the kSbEventTypeSuspend event, instead you can send the kSbEventTypePause event.  See the Cobalt lifecycle document for more information: https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/release_11/src/cobalt/doc/lifecycle.md .